# Should mqueues be protected by semaphores

Tags: c, linux, posix, mqueue

Should read `mq_receive` and write `mq_send` be protected by semaphores when accessing a queue in a multiprocess program or is there any sort of protection alredy built in

Comment: Shared resources between threads need synchronisation for data integrity & consistency.

Comment: @SparKot The idea of message queues, that they implement the inter-process synchronization intrinsically.

Comment: *is there any sort of protection already built in* - yes, there is. This is exactly the idea of having message queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always recomended to read the formal documentation for API you are using.

Specifcally for `mq_receive` and `mq_send` these are:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_send.3.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html

In the **atributes section** you can see that both these functions are **thread safe**, meaning you can access them from multiple threads without additional protection.